# Simple function to apply on a dataframe but ambigous for python

Tags: python, pandas

Hello and thank in advance for reading this.

I have a dataframe on which I would like to compare two quantities x and y

```
def test(x,y) : 

    if x == y :
        return (x,0)

    elif (x > y) :
        off = x - y 
        on = x - off
        return (on, off)
    else : 
        off = y - x
        on = y - off
        return (on, off)
```

but when I want to apply it to my dataframe

```
df.apply(lambda x : test(df["quantite_1"], df["quantite_2"]), axis =1)
```

I have this

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I understand that something's wrong with the parameters of my function, but I can't tell what. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error it's because you're using `df["quantite_1"], df["quantite_2"]` as parameter, you should use this instead:

```
df.apply(lambda x : test(x["quantite_1"], x["quantite_2"]), axis =1)
```